# Why is there a 5V linear regulator on this USB ATTiny85 dev board?

Tags: usb-device, linear-regulator, attiny85

[This](https://ardushop.ro/303-thickbox_default/attiny85-usb-development-board.jpg) dev board. 78M05G regulator, attiny85 MCU.

[image: Schematic]

Similar (ON MC78Mx05) regulators' dropout voltage is listed at 2V0. USB voltage is specified at 5V0 (+0V25)(-0V55). The ATTiny85 can take 2V7 to 5V5, though for some variants the 4V45 low end of the USB spec straddles a speed grade.

By my understanding you're operating in undefined territory if you are below the sum of output voltage and dropout voltage, which would be 7V here. So why the linear regulator? Alternatively, what am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the sign. Specifically, the "-" sign.

Comment: We need to see a schematic and datasheet/usermanual for this board. It appears that you have some options for supplying power, but the schematic would tell us.

Comment: Maple, where am I missing this sign? In the summation of dropout and output voltage? I don't think that's how it works... but I could be mistaken I guess. I don't think it's the ATTiny's input voltage. I don't think it's the USB voltage spec. Clarification?

Comment: Thanks Elliot. After digging that up it looks like it's a regulator for power applied to the JP2-1 pin. I'll answer and close out.

Comment: @fiddling_junky you are supposed to substract (drop out) dropout voltage from input. 5V - 2V = 3V. Or, if you look at [78M05G datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/670/78M05G-T60-K.php) it provides more precise 3.5V output value at 5V input and 200mA draw

Comment: I'm not sure that's actually true, maple. In any case, nanofarad answered the question adequately. Thanks for looking out, though!

Comment: @fiddling_junky Which part are you not sure about? Note, that regardless of what you think about regulator's working principles, 5V USB power is NOT used to supply 78M05G per your board schematics.

Comment: Yes, I'm now aware that the regulator isn't in line with the USB 5V, which is why I marked Nano's answer as accepted. I definitely should have looked up the schematic first. Regarding the question, to ensure my sanity I just checked 5 sources, from Wikipedia to random how-to pages to the datasheet for the TI TPS7A20, and they all say V_in must be above nominal V_out+V_DO for good operation. Specifically, TI defines V_DO by the voltage above nominal V_out(nom) at which V_in must be for V_out to drop to no lower than 95% of V_out(nom). In any case, we've moved away from my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theoretical understanding of a voltage regulator's dropout voltage and operation is correct. It indeed requires at least +7V to operate within its specifications because its output voltage is +5V and its dropout voltage is 2V.

However, the voltage regulator is not where you think it is. It supplies +5V to the attiny's supply pins, taking its input from the Vin pin, and is used as an alternative when +5V power is not available via either a USB port or other power supply.

This, and your concerns related to dropout voltage, are confirmed by the part's specifications listing:

> Tensiune de intrare (recomandat): 7-35 V

or translated:

> Input voltage (recommended): 7-35 V

This presumably refers to the Vin pin, whilst the +5 V pin and USB VBUS alike are intended to be used strictly within the USB/attiny supply voltage specifications.

Comment: Thanks! I'd just gotten there from Elliot's comment.

Comment: @fiddling_junky Not a problem, happy to help.

Comment: " clean +5V power is not available via either a USB port".  Not sure I would call USB 5V clean...